# React Typescript: Passing both children and props through function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I have a wrapper component called 'Layout.tsx' which is, as the name suggests, the wrapper for all my other pages and has stuff like Navigation, Footer, etc. I'm already passing children through, but I also want to pass props, as I want to move some state from one of its child components into another component that is referenced inside of it.

Layout.tsx

```
import React from "react";

...

import Alert from "../global/Alert";

export default function Layout({ children }, props: any) {
  
  ...

  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
        
      ...

      <Alert isVisible={props.isVisible} message={props.message} />
        
      ...

      <section className={styles.content} style={{ transform: `translateY(${(isOpenNav === "false") ? "0vh" : "-45vh"})` }} onClick={() => setIsOpenNav("false")}>
        {children}
      </section>

      ...
      
    </main>
  );
}
```

Alert.tsx (other component, not child)

```
import styles from "./styles/Alert.module.scss";

export default function Alert(props: any) {
  return (
    <main className={styles.main} style={{ display: props.isVisible ? "flex" : "none" }}>
      {props.message.title}
    </main>
  );
}
```

ShopItem.tsx (child component)

```
import React from "react";

...

import Layout from "./layout/Layout";

...

export default function ShopItem() {

  ...

  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <Layout isVisible={isVisible} message={{ title: "hello" }}>
      ...
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

The idea is that I want to activate the Alert.tsx component whenever a user presses a certain button in the ShopItem.tsx component. However, I keep getting this error:

```
Type '{ children: Element; isVisible: boolean; message: { title: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children: any; }'.
  Property 'isVisible' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children: any; }'.ts(2322)
(property) isVisible: boolean
```

Answer (score 2):

The error you're seeing suggests that the object you're attempting to pass is not compatible with the type of the `props` prop in the `Layout` component. You're trying to pass an object with the `isVisible` and `message` properties, but the `props` prop should have the type `IntrinsicAttributes & { children: any; }`.

You must specifically describe the type of the `props` prop in the `Layout` component to fix this problem. A type declaration placed above the `Layout` component will accomplish this:

```
type LayoutProps = {
  isVisible: boolean;
  message: {
    title: string;
  };
};

function Layout({ children }: LayoutProps, props: any) {
  // ...
}
```

This instructs TypeScript that the `props` prop ought to belong to the `LayoutProps` type, encompassing the `message` and `isVisible` properties. By doing this, the type problem ought to be fixed and you should be able to send the required props from the `ShopItem` component to the `Layout` component.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried the new change, and it seems to have worked.

Comment: Glad, it was helpful. 